# Filter dataframe and create a plot based on start and end date

Tags: r, shiny

I have data set that I have transformed into following format and drawing a graph based on it.

```
    structure(list(Date = structure(c(17833, 17830, 17829, 17828, 
NA), class = "Date"), stocks = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("DBS SP Equity", "OCBC SP Equity", "ST SP Equity"
), class = "factor"), cumulative = c(22.99, 23.1, 23.71, 24.1, 
NA), Industry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Banks", 
"Telecommunications"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have 2 input fields : Industry and DateRange.

My input

```
selectInput(inputId = "industry2",
                  label = "Industry",
                  choices = input_selection[input_selection !='MarketIndex'],
                  selected = NULL, 
                  multiple = TRUE),
      dateRangeInput('dateRange',
      label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
      start = min(sharesdata_gather$Date), end = max(sharesdata_gather$Date))
```

I am able to plot the 2 graph - Industry vs Date and Stock Vs Date for all the data in my original datastructure.
But cannot plot the graph only for the dates specified by the user. I tried subset function to filter the graph but get error of "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"

My server function is :

```
#filtering the data for input start and end date                 
dailyprice_gather <- subset(dailyprice_gather, Date>=input$dateRange[1] )
             dailyprice_gather <- subset(dailyprice_gather, Date<=input$dateRange[2] )
           #grap for Date vs Cumulative for each industry
             output$ind=renderPlot({
            ggplot(data = dailyprice_gather[dailyprice_gather$Industry == input$industry2,]) +
          geom_line(aes(x= Date , y= cumulative, color=Industry) , size=0.25) +

               ggtitle(paste0("Simple Cumulative Return over Years - Industry Wise"))

             })
             #graph for Date vs Stock 
              output$stk =renderPlot({
              ggplot(data = dailyprice_gather[dailyprice_gather$Industry == input$industry2  & dailyprice_gather$stocks == input$equities,])+
          geom_line(aes(x= Date , y= cumulative, color=stocks) , size=0.25) +
              ggtitle(paste0("Simple Cumulative Return over Years - Stock Wise"))

             })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use *input$dateRange[1]* outside any active reactive context - so if the user changes the value, then nothing would react to it and *dailyprice_gather* won't be updated.

Try using

```
dailyprice_gather <- reactive({
    d <- subset(<original data name>, Date>=input$dateRange[1] )
    d <- subset(d, Date<=input$dateRange[2] )
    d
)}
```

and refer to it as *dailyprice_gather()*. So whenever the date range is changed, the above reactive will be invalidated and anything which depends on it will be rerun. Note that you need to replace "original data name".

Comment: @radmuzon , Thank you for answering this . But Iam not very clear , how i implement it in my code.I added  `dailyprice_gather <- reactive({
    d <- subset(dailyprice_gather, Date>=input$dateRange[1] )
    d <- subset(d, Date<=input$dateRange[2] )
    d
})`  But I get object of type 'closure' is not subsettable  [No stack trace available] error. I guess I have to call d() somewhere but not sure where

Comment: What is the name of your original data which you want to subset? Is it *dailyprice_gather*? Then name the reactive something else - you can think of the reactive as a function which will return a different dataset every time the date range changes. The dataset you want to subset should be used in the original *subset* and the reactive should be called like a function.